# Explain BASH code line let RETVAL=$((RETVAL|$?))

Tags: bash, shell

I'm looking for some explanation of the below line of BASH from a shell script. I'm generally familiar with all the individual builtins and the use of $(( )). I'm a bit confused about what the bitwise OR operator is comparing in this line.

```
let RETVAL=$((RETVAL|$?))
```

Comment: It's the bitwise OR operator. Read the section of the Bash Manual about Arithmetic Evaluation.

Comment: This is strange code, as `$?` is not usually a bitmask, so it doesn't usually make sense to process it with bitwise operators. But maybe this script is part of an application that puts bitmasks in exit codes.

Comment: Here's an example using the same line without the let command https://searchcode.com/file/18630848/deluge-daemon-init/

Comment: The arithmetic (( compound )) command should almost always be preferred than `let`. http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/let

Comment: `let` and `$((...))` together are redundant. You can write `RETVAL=$((RETVAL | $?))`, or you can write `let RETVAL="$RETVAL|$?"`. You don't need both, and neither alternative helps explain why the binary-OR is being used in the first place.

Comment: `let` itself is essentially obsolete. You can use `(( RETVAL |= $? ))` as well using the arithmetic statement.

Comment: @chepner, this is an idiom I use quite frequently in my own code (granted, more like `(( retval |= $? ))`, but still). Makes it easy to track "did any of these processes fail?", and in cases where the distinction between exit status matters, I usually _am_ making those bitmasks.

Answer (score 2):

Inside *double* parentheses, the expression is evaluated not as a command, but as an [arithmetic expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html#Shell-Arithmetic).

Consequently, this is not a pipe operator but a *bitwise or* operator.

In this case, it will set any bits in the variable `RETVAL` which are set in the result of the last statement (as contained in the special variable `$?`).

It's possible that this is just abusing bitwise or as a logical operator, since the result will be zero (generally interpreted as success / true) only if both the previous value of `RETVAL` and `$?` are zero. In other words, repeatedly using this after multiple commands gives you a zero result only if they all returned zero.

Comment: Thanks, that helps some. I understand that the pipe operator is acting as a bitwise OR expression. I suppose my more specific question is; why use this logic? To answer that question would likely require more context with this project though

Comment: @ChaseSchuette, ...perhaps extend the question to clarify what you already know and what you meant to ask; when you say "pipe operator" instead of "bitwise or operator", it certainly _implies_ to readers that you don't know that being in arithmetic context changes the meaning.

Comment: Thanks. Reading the comments has shown me to be careful with the use of the terms "pipe operator" and "bitwise OR operator".

Answer (score 1):

This generally means someone is ORing together the exit status of several different operations to come up with a combined exit status.

`let` is an antiquated way of entering an arithmetic context; `(( ))` and `$(( ))` are the modern alternatives; the code below is thus going to prefer the more modern bash-only syntax (`$(( ))` is both modern and portable but makes you responsible for ensuring that the value it evaluates to has no unintended side effects, whereas `(( ))` is modern but not portable, and `let` is neither portable nor modern).

Let's say that you want to always run functions `foo1`, `foo2`, and `foo3`, and report whether any of them failed:

```
main() {
  local retval=0 # local is the only non-POSIX thing in this example
  foo1 || : $(( retval |= $? ))
  foo2 || : $(( retval |= $? ))
  foo3 || : $(( retval |= $? ))
  return "$retval"
}
```

...will return an exit status that determines whether *any* of foo1, foo2, or foo3 failed; and if their exit status works as a bitmask, will set high bits to indicate which failure modes took place.

---

Using `||` instead of `;` is done to make it explicit that the exit status of the commands on the left-hand side are "checked", so `set -e` or `ERR` traps will not trigger should they be nonzero.

Using lowercase variable names is done for compliance with the conventions specified in https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, whereby all-caps names are used for variables meaningful to POSIX-specified tools, whereas names with at least one lower-case character are reserved for application use and guaranteed not to have unintended side effects on POSIX-specified tools. (Because setting a regular shell variable overwrites any like-named environment variable, the same conventions apply to both types).